# Any way to deploy a Meteor web app as a standalone self-contained package?

Tags: meteor

I'm wondering if there's a way to deploy Meteor apps in a way that someone could download it, unzip it, then run it so that basically it runs Mongo, runs a Node.js web server, and opens up the browser to (e.g.) `http://localhost:4040` where the app will then run. All in one shot, fully self-contained. So no need to put it on a Linux server, install Mongo, set env vars, all that stuff.

Comment: Maybe you could make it work with [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit)

Comment: Whoa! Very interesting. That looks like something that might work for me. Will investigate further.

Comment: curious to find out how this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be possible with [Electron (formerly Atom-Shell)](http://electron.atom.io/). There is tutorial on [medium.com](https://medium.com/@guidouil/cross-platform-desktop-apps-with-meteor-and-electron-5355eb9e351) and a package called [meteor-electron](https://github.com/jrudio/meteor-electron).

Also check out existing questions

1. [Building a pure offline Meteor app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787917/building-a-pure-offline-meteor-app/27794917#27794917)
2. [Desktop applications with Meteor.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207124/desktop-applications-with-meteor-js)

UPDATE!

3. [Electrometeor - Desktop Applications w/ Electron + Meteor](https://forums.meteor.com/t/electrometeor-desktop-applications-w-electron-meteor/3768)