# Meteor app launching issue while offline

Tags: cordova, meteor, startup, offline, iron-router

I have a meteor app (with cordova) using Iron-router. It works fine, but when I try to open the app offline then it hangs forever on the loading screen. There is no problem when connected to the internet.

here is an extract of my config.js file:

```
this.Config = {
  name: 'MyApp',
  title: function() {
    return TAPi18n.__('configTitle');
  },
  subtitle: function() {
    return TAPi18n.__('configSubtitle');
  },
  logo: function() {
    return '<b>' + this.name + '</b>';
  },
  homeRoute: '/',
  publicRoutes: ['home']
};
```

and here is what my main.js file looks like:

```
Router.route('/', {
  name: 'home',
  layoutTemplate: 'homeLayout',
  onBeforeAction: function () { this.render();   }
});
```

Note: I already found the answer, but since I looked for it so long, maybe some other will find this helpful

Config:
meteor 1.6
Iron-router 1.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer: Iron-router doesn't like the "/" route definition in config.js

So simply change `"/"` to `"home"` and it will work!

I resolved this using the suggestion from [Akshat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27794917)